# System Preferences Closes When I Click On Apparence

Tags: system-settings

If I open my System Preferences, anything goes smoothly and good. But when I click on Apparence, the System Preferences close and a window will pop up saying that "an intern fail appeared".

I'm using a 12.04 Ubuntu 32 bit LTS version

Comment: They are the same program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are managed by the gnome-control-center binary. Hence, whenever you open one or the other it uses the same window in a way to not waste resources. Until now, I haven't found a way to force more than one window open.

Comment: Ive updated my OS and it workes again, Thanks though for the help